# Logitech Web camera on KVM windows 7 VM created with virt-manager

Tags: virtual-machine, webcam, kvm

in host machine the output of lsusb is: Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:0819 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C210

I want to use this webcam in the VM. I am clicking "add hardware" in virt-manager and usb host device -> 002:002, so physical usb device 002:002 has been added.

Inside now the windows VM, in the device manager, it recognises new hardware but installs it as: NEC USB hub

The result is that the camera is not working, no program can see a camera. Any help?

PS: The camera works normally in the host machine, I have tested it with cheese program. So I could imaging that adding the hardware in the VM it should work..

Comment: I don't have a full solution, but this might help.

I read that by default, virt-manage creates a lot of USB redirection so for some limit in the system, is not possible to use more. (http://askubuntu.com/questions/564708/qemu-kvm-virt-manager-passthrough-of-usb-webcam-to-windows-7-enterprise-creates) (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1135488).

They say that removing them might solve the problem, but I can't solve it.